# Automatic award of bounty

Tags: discussion

I posted a question [Performance deteriorating after async postback - scrolling becomes horrendous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359065/performance-deteriorating-after-async-postback-scrolling-becomes-horrendous) and the info section says that the bounty will be auto awarded - although my question is not answered.

Is there a way to "re-bounty" this, or should I just re-open a new question with the same content???  if I am doing something wrong maybe we can reword the info at the bottom stating what my options are, in addition, re-bounty it / award bounty / etc...?

Basically what are my options here...I think I want to offer a bigger bounty to maybe attract more interest?  But I don't know how to proceed, for instance, the current answers don't really help me so I dont want to offer a bounty and give the idea that my question is closed - its not really closed.

Comment: -1 for what?  For asking how to take the right path without affecting the site by duplicating data.  Come on people...

Comment: You wait until your current bounty expires, and apply another one, if you're not satisfied with the results.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - don't you think that will help users by stating that?  Or did I miss it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If neither answer reaches a score of +2, they will not be [automatically awarded the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/186281).

> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

---

If they didn't answer the question, I suggest down voting (to prevent the automatic award). I'd also comment as to why they don't answer the question in the original post, so that future visitors see what hasn't worked and why. If you want to re-bounty, you can do so after the grace period is over, but it will require you to [double the previous amount you bountied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639).

Comment: So basically I need to wait for the "you have 21 hours to award the bounty" to expire?

Comment: Yes. You wait for it to expire, then decide if you want to re-bounty or not.

Comment: Okay, but it would help to somehow indicate that on the fyi notice div that states that an auto bounty will be awarded automagically.  Something to the effect of if(bountyNotAwardedYet) state it!

Comment: The comment is always useful, unless the answer is really beyond hopeless. In the ideal case, they will correct any deficit before the grace-period is over.

Comment: Hey @Andy, this is wrong or it could actually be a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56382753/495455 - I followed all the criteria and didn't get the bounty? **any idea why?**

Comment: You answered before the bounty was issued. Those answers aren't eligible for automatic awards. The one that was automatically selected answered within the bounty period